# How to see a patch file nicely with PHPStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

This is how I see a patch file (file.patch) with Sublime Text:
[image]

And here with PHPStorm:
[image]

There is any plugin to see a patch file nice like Sublime Text with PHPStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEA-74005](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74005)